# XML::Twig is adding empty newline for values provided in multi-line

Tags: xml, perl, twig, xml-twig

I am using XML::Twig to parse the file in my perl script. I am bit new to this. I got following kind of entries (sample example here) in my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mytag1 name="abc">
    <mytag2>This is line 1.
        This is line 2.
        This is line 3.
     </mytag2>
</mytag1>
```

And in my perl script, I am doing something like:

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new( keep_encoding=>1, keep_atts_order=>1, pretty_print => 'indented', comments => 'keep' );
$twig->parsefile($in_file);
```

I have some validation code around after which following kind of output is getting generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mytag1 name="abc">
    <mytag2>This is line 1.

        This is line 2.

        This is line 3.

     </mytag2>
</mytag1>
```

The extra blank lines are getting generated in output, I am not sure what's going wrong. I tried to search around but couldn't find much useful information on this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how do you generate the output? it's not shown in your code. FWIW when I do `$twig->print` I don't get the extra empty lines

Comment: @mirod, What if the original had CRLF line endings?

Comment: @ikegami, the parser normalizes those "to a single #xA character" (https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends)... oh wait! Not with `keep_encoding`! that's it, that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `keep_encoding` option. It's useless since the input is in utf-8, and it makes the module bypass some of the parser features, notably the one that normalizes LF/CR

It should not be used anyway: it's a relic of a time when Unicode was not as prevalent as today. It allowed people stuck with old encodings to still be able to process their XML.

Thanks ikegami!

Comment: Thanks a lot, removing keep_encoding did resolve the issue but just wondering would it have any impact? Because in this example the encoding is "UTF-8" but that won't be the case always.

Comment: By default the encoding of the output will be utf-8, if you know the encoding ahead of time you can use a filter `   my $conv = XML::Twig::encode_convert( 'latin1');   my $t = XML::Twig->new(output_filter => $conv);` or you can do the conversion back to the original encoding as a separate step using `iconv` for example. It is pretty rare these days to work with anything else than unicode (UTF-8 in *nix, I guess it could be UTF-16 on windows).